# How to have an asp.net mvc app receive simple text string data from a client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am implementing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that needs to receive data from a client, but I am uncertain how to do this.

The client is a GPS tracking unit that delivers a longitude and a latitude every 10 sec. The data is a comma separated text string so only very small amounts of data, the whole string is around 40 characters long.

Once I have the data I will display the longitude and latitude as simple text in my application. The data should only be displayed realtime and not saved/stored in any db or anything. I can configure the client to connect through GPRS to whatever IP:Port address I want.

I have implemented a simple server using Winform which runs on my local machine using `TcpListener` and `StreamReader`. I can get the client to connect to this one, and can get the data no problem. But not sure how to make this in my asp.net application. Should I implement `TcpListener` in my viewmodel? I suspect that this is not the right way to do it.

It should just be as simple a solution as possible.

Any help or links to examples will be much appreciated.

Best regards Kasper

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR .SignalR is a new developer's API provided for ASP.NET web applications, used to add "real time" web functionality to ASP.NET applications.

Check out following link for more information

[Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2 and MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc)

Comment: Thanks. 
So I should be able to use SignalR in my ASP.NET app. and then have that listen for the "data" from my client? Then i guess I just need to find out how to setup the port in SignalR and then have my client send the "data" to that IP and port?

Comment: @KasperJuulLarsen :  Right

Comment: And this will work eventhough the client is not setup to use the Signalr hubs? I don't have control on the SW of the client I can only set it up to connect to an IP address and a port.